# Es posible guardar informacion en los items de un List View Android

Tags: android

Tengo un List view que lleno despues de una peticion Rest. En la respuesta recibo codigo,actividad y descripcion. Lo que quiero es que en el listview sea vea la lista de descripciones y que cuando se le de click se muestre el codigo. Una especie de data-attribute como en HTML5.  Es esto posible o hay que hacer la peticion rest nuevamente para traer el codigo ??????

```
public void get() {


        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String url="https://actividadescomerciales.herokuapp.com/actividades";

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(

                Request.Method.GET, url, null,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        Log.i("sizejson","get");

                        obtenerjson(response);


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        text1.setText(error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);



    }

    public void obtenerjson(JSONArray response) {

        ArrayList<String> lis=new ArrayList<String>();

        for ( int a=0;a<response.length();a++){

            try {

                lis.add(response.getJSONObject(a).getString("actividad"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                text1.setText(e.toString());

            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adap=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,lis);

        lista.setAdapter(adap);

    }
```

Comment: Agrega tu código, estas usando objetos para poblar el ListView? revisa [ask].

Comment: @Elenasys Listo!!

Answer (score 0):

si se puede hacer y hay varias formas, lo que yo te recomiendo es que primero modeles los datos. Luego con el indice del item seleccionado recuperas el modelo del array y ahi vas a tener la informacion para mostrarla como quieras.

Con modelar los datos me refiero a que crees una clase que contenga los campos que trae el json, porque con el codigo que tenes ahi solo estas guardando la actividad y los demas campos los estas perdiendo.

```
// El modelo puede ser algo asi
public class Actividad {
  public String codigo;
  public String actividad;
  public String descripcion; 
}
```

Ahora cuando parsees los datos vas a conseguir un Array de Actividades en lugar de  un Array de Strings. El codigo deberia quedar algo asi:

```
public ArrayList<Actividad> obtenerjson(JSONArray response) {

  ArrayList<Actividad> lis = new ArrayList<Actividad>();
  for ( int a=0;a<response.length();a++){
    Actividad modelo = new Actividad();
    try {
      modelo.actividad = response.getJSONObject(a).getString("actividad");
      modelo.codigo = response.getJSONObject(a).getString("codigo");
      modelo.descripcion = response.getJSONObject(a).getString("descripcion");
      lis.add(modelo);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      text1.setText(e.toString());
     }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Guarda la ArrayList que devuelva este metodo en tu Activity o Fragment y usalo para crear tu adapter y para recuperar la descripcion cuando lo necesites.